# Is it possible to use Poedit to read from XML files but only the labels?

Tags: xml, poedit

I've already found the working  code to get lang definitions from XML files with this code: 
    `Language: XML
    List of extensions separated by semicolons: *.xml
    Parser command: xgettext -LC --extract-all -o %o %C %F
    An item in keywords list:
    Item in input files list: %f
    source code charset: --from-code=%c`

However this code gives back the name part too, which i don't want. Do you have any idea how to filter to "label" only?